# Using GridView with variable width elements

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview, itemscontrol

I have a GridView and need to set width elements to Stretch as it's content, for now my Gridview looks like this image

[image]

I want something like this:

[image]

I think something like change **ItemsTemplate** to an StackPanel, but some samples found on the web are not enough clear for me.

How can I do to change The ItemsTemplate to get the behavior I want?

or

There is another XAML control that allow me to get this behavior?

**Note:** I'm using VS 2015, performing a UWP app.

Comment: Have you tried ItemsControl ? You set the ItemTemplate to a Stackpanel and set the ItemSource to what you want!

Comment: No, I don't know about it. I'm going to look for a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Window.Resources>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate"> 
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ItemsControl  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding List}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>


</Window>
```

In code behind I have this to simulate:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.List = new List<string> { "Quien", "vie", "ne", "en", "su", "nom", "bre" };
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        public List<string> List { get; set; }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excelent thats just what I need :)

Comment: Just need to solve something, My list has elements with an space **" "**  "word's separator" this sample cut out them and I need to show it to. .

Comment: Can you explain better? I tried to this.List = new List<string> { "Quien  ", "vie  ", "ne", "en  ", "su", "nom", "bre" }
and the words were shown with the spaces

Comment: My List<string> { "Quien"," " ,"vie", "ne"," ","en"," ","su"," ","nom", "bre"}, comes from a syntactic analizar. But for now I added a **MinWidth="10"** to the template. Again very tks for your help..